# Unable to connect Quic-Go sever

Tags: quic

I follow the wiki from https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go and I run:

```
go run example/main.go -bind "0.0.0.0:6121"
```

I'm running the server in a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine and I use port redirection of 11220 (my open port on the host) to 6121 (the port of the server in the virtual machine).

Then, I use another computer and I run

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\tmp --no-proxy-server --enable-quic --origin-to-force-quic-on=quic.clemente.io:443 --host-resolver-rules='MAP quic.clemente.io:443 X.X.X.X:11220' https://quic.clemente.io
```

where X.X.X.X is my public IP. An I get a chrome error:
"Unable to access this web site: ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

How could I make a proper quic connection from another host?